# Autohotkey - I am left handed and would like CTRL - UP to work like WIN - TAB

Tags: autohotkey

I have been trying for a couple of hour to try and get CTRL - UPKEY to work as WIN - TAB.  This is similar to Mac actually but would help me a lot as a leftie.

^Up::#Tab

is the closest I got but not working.

Comment: Try **`^Up::Send #{Tab}`** or **`^Up::Send {LWin Down}{Tab}{LWin Up}`**

Answer (score 2):

You were very close! As @user3419297 mentioned, one working solution would be `^Up::Send #{Tab}`. Here is why this new syntax works as opposed to the original one:

1. <s>If we wish to create a hotkey to send inputs more than a basic `Key a --> Key b` remapping (for which your original syntax would work)</s>, we need to use the [`Send`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) command.

Edit: This would actually proper syntax normally- the reason it didn't work had to do with [`SendMode Blind`](https://documentation.help/AutoHotKey-Functions/Send.htm#blind) that `a::b` remappings use.

(current code at this point: `^Up::Send #Tab`)

2. Because <kbd>Tab</kbd> is a special key, we need to surround it by curly braces `{}` in order to convey this to AutoHotkey.

---

### Final code:

```
^Up::Send #{Tab}
```

Hope this helped you understand why these differences are needed. Feel free to let me know if you need more clarification on this!

Comment: There is actually nothing wrong with `^Up::#Tab`, it just doesn't work in this specific case due to blind sendmode.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I've updated the post to reflect this